# When i enter my discord bot token in visualstudiocode and i run it in command prompt it doesent work

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

My token for my discord bot isn't working.

When I go into the command prompt and I type `node .`, it says:

```
Syntax Error: Invalid or unexpected token
```

I'm pretty sure nothing is wrong with my code.

Heres my code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = "?";

client.once("ready", () => {
  console.log("KeyBot is online!");
});

client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === "ping") {
    message.channel.send("pong!");
  }
});

const args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1);
const user = message.mentions.users.first();
const banReason = args.slice(1).join(" ");

if (!user) {
  try {
    if (!message.guild.members.get(args.slice(0, 1).join(" ")))
      throw new Error("Couldn't get a Discord user with this userID!");

    user = message.guild.members.get(args.slice(0, 1).join(" "));
    user = user.user;
  } catch (error) {
    return message.reply("Couldn' get a Discord user with this userID!");
  }
}
if (user === message.author)
  return message.channel.send("You can't ban yourself");
if (!reason) return message.reply("You forgot to enter a reason for this ban!");
if (!message.guild.member(user).bannable)
  return message.reply(
    "You can't ban this user because you the bot has not sufficient permissions!"
  );
await message.guild.ban(user);
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const banConfirmationEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setColor("RED")
  .setDescription(`✅ ${user.tag} has been successfully banned!`);
message.channel.send({
  embed: banConfirmationEmbed,
});
const modlogChannelID = "";
if (modlogChannelID.length !== 0) {
  if (!client.channels.get(modlogChannelID)) return undefined;
  const banConfirmationEmbedModlog = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setAuthor(
      `Banned by **${msg.author.username}#${msg.author.discriminator}**`,
      msg.author.displayAvatarURL
    )
    .setThumbnail(user.displayAvatarURL)
    .setColor("RED")
    .setTimestamp().setDescription(`**Action**: Ban
     **User**: ${user.username}#${user.discriminator} (${user.id})
     **Reason**: ${reason}`);
  client.channels.get(modlogChannelID).send({
    embed: banConfirmationEmbedModlog,
  });
}

const args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1);
const amount = args.join(" ");

if (!amount)
  return msg.reply(
    "You haven't given an amount of messages which should be deleted!"
  );
if (isNaN(amount)) return msg.reply("The amount parameter isn`t a number!");

if (amount > 100)
  return msg.reply("You can`t delete more than 100 messages at once!");
if (amount < 1) return msg.reply("You have to delete at least 1 message!");

await msg.channel.messages
  .fetch({
    limit: amount,
  })
  .then((messages) => {
    msg.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
  });

client.login("token");
```

Comment: Did you replace `'token'` with your actual token? Or did you log in with the literal string `'token'`

Comment: On my code i have my actual token

Comment: Try regenerating your token and replacing it in your actual code

Comment: I just did that but it still says invalid or unexpected token in command prompt

Comment: As noted by the error message this is a Syntax Error, not a Discord JS error. This usually means you have a typo in your code, this has nothing to do with your actual bot token. What is the full error message? Does it say on which line the error occurs?

Comment: Your ban handling command looks like it's being executed outside of the message event, including code using 'await', which is not accepted outside an async function

Comment: You are using await outside an async function. It is the syntax error.